# SQL UPDATE using CASE WHEN with PHP variable as argument

Tags: php, sql, case

I have a database storing materials in their respective formats, i.e. The Idiot (novel), Hamlet (play), Star Wars (screenplay), etc.

I'm using a PHP function that removes articles (i.e. The/A/An/', etc.) and creates a variable ($mat_alph, assigned NULL if non-existent) by which it can later be alphabetised.  This is only required for titles with articles, but for those without one, I want this saved in the database as a NULL value.

Saving the variable in a NULL state stores it as an empty string rather than an actual NULL value, which causes problems later when filtering results by IS NULL/IS NOT NULL (which I'll need to do when using SELECT commands with CASE WHEN to call mat_nm for those without an article and mat_alph for those with).  I don't want to save a mat_alph value for titles without an article as this will apply to a huge amount, repeating the mat_nm value and wasting memory.

Is it possible to use CASE WHEN in an UPDATE statement using the PHP variable as the argument?

The below attempt handles titles without articles well enough (i.e. Hamlet updates mat_alph to NULL) but with articles (i.e. The Idiot) creates this error:-

Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'Idiot'

```
$sql=   "UPDATE mat SET
        mat_nm='$mat_nm',
        mat_alph=CASE WHEN ('$mat_alph') THEN '$mat_alph' END,
        mat_url='$mat_url',
        frmtid=(SELECT frmt_id FROM frmt WHERE frmt_url='$frmt_url')
        WHERE mat_id='$mat_id'";
```

Is this possible or do I need a separate SQL UPDATE command solely for updating the mat_alph field?

The problem also applies to the initial INSERT commands and I expect the solution will apply to both.

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO mat(mat_nm, mat_alph, mat_url, frmtid)
        SELECT '$mat_nm', '$mat_alph', '$mat_url', frmt_id FROM frmt WHERE frmt_url='$frmt_url'";
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: im confused are you asking about php variables in strings or mysql queries?

Comment: Using a PHP variable which I want to enter into the MySQL database but using it as an argument in a CASE statement as part of the SQL UPDATE statement.

Comment: does this explain the php variables: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Q088Yt

Comment: Yes - the CASE statement is to confirm the existence of $mat_alph, hence the simplicity of that argument (I presume that's what it's doing as it seems to be able to acknowledge NULL variables as such).

Comment: Can you add the PHP function that removes the articles? It will be helpful to see how `$mat_alph` is generated. If too long to add, check on your end the returned value of `$mat_alph` when "The Idiot" or any title with articles is passed through.

Comment: `function alph($a) 
{
 if(preg_match('/^(A |An |The |\W+)(\S+.*)$/i', $a)) {$alph=preg_replace('/^(A |An |The |\W+)(\S+.*)$/i', '$2', $a);}
 else {$alph=NULL;}
 return $alph;
}
$mat_alph=alph($mat_nm);`
Returned value of mat_alph is 'Idiot', as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument needed the correct syntax.  Three solutions:-

```
mat_alph=CASE WHEN NULLIF('$mat_alph','') IS NOT NULL THEN '$mat_alph' END

mat_alph=CASE WHEN '$mat_alph'='' THEN NULL ELSE '$mat_alph' END

mat_alph=CASE WHEN '$mat_alph'!='' THEN '$mat_alph' END
```

The last is a shorter version of the second which works because NULL is given as a default for non-matching cases.

Credit to [r937](http://community.sitepoint.com/users/r937/activity).